# Disable Document Parser using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom

I am currently using CSOM site provisioning to spin up Community sites on demand. The sites have a document promotion feature which requires the Document Parser to be disabled. I know this can be done vi Powershell, but I was wondering if it could be done via CSOM during the provisioning process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This property is not supported yet in CSOM.

Check the uservoice request and upvote it.

[Support the Web.ParserEnabled property in CSOM](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/15147189-support-the-web-parserenabled-property-in-csom)

Using Powershell;

```
$web=Get-SPweb "http://siteurl/"
## Set the ParserEnabled property to False to disable the document property promotion
$web.ParserEnabled=$false
$web.Update()
```

Using C# SSOM:

```
web.ParserEnabled = false;
web.Update();
```

Comment: This is sort of what I figured, but wanted to double check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in CSOM for the Web class.

An alternative is to do it for every list in those sites

[List.ParserDisabled = true](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.parserdisabled.aspx)